# When does the recursive sequence $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{1+ba_n}$ converge, and what does it converge to?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, recursion

> Let $b$ and $a_0$ be real numbers and $(a_n)$ a sequence such that:
> $$a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{1+ba_n}$$
> For what values of $b$ and $a_0$ does this sequence converge, and to what number does it converge to?

This seems to be a common problem given to Calculus students, given $b=2$ and $a_0=1$. In that case, it converges to $\frac12$. A friend of mine is wondering about the general case given above, so I'm asking here. We have been able to make a few observations:

- It is undefined if $a_0 b = -1$.
- It seems to converge for positive values of $b$ and $a_0$.
- It seems to diverge if either $b$ is negative, no matter the $a_0$.
- With $b$ fixed at $2$ and $a_0=-1$, the sequence converges to $-1$. Is there any other $a_0$ such that also happens?

We haven't really been able to prove any of the above except the first, probably because we're not used to dealing with the convergence of recursive sequences specifically, so some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: suppose the limits exist and it's finite. Call it $\;\alpha\;$ , then: using the recursive formula and aritmethic of limits we get $$\alpha=\frac1{1+b\alpha}\implies b\alpha^2+\alpha-1=0$$ This last quadratic in $\;\alpha\;$ has a real solution iff $\;1+4b\ge0\;$ . Take it from here.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I think you meant  the quadratic has real solution iff $1+4b \ge 0$.

Comment: @NN2 Of course. Good catch, thank you. Edited.

Comment: @DonAntonio Ah, thank you! It's much simpler than what I thought.

Comment: @Hardly In case you want to find the closed-form solution of $a_n$, just denote $a_n= x_n /x_{n+1}$ with $x_0=1$, then
$$ \iff\frac{x_{n+2}}{x_{n+1}}=1+b\frac{x_{n}}{x_{n+1}} \iff x_{n+2} =x_{n+1}+bx_n \tag{*}$$
And you can find easily the closed form solution of $(x_n)_n$ from $(*)$.

Comment: @NN2 Thank you. If I may, could I ask some clarification on the 4th observation I made in the OP? While it is clear that for $b=2$ and $a_0=-1$ the limit is $-1$ because of the solution of the quadratic, I am still not sure how do I find the exact $a_0$ that gives the "other" limit of the sequence given a certain $b$.

Comment: @Hardly For the case $b = 2$, you can use the method I proposed (the 5th comment) to find the closed form solution of $(x_n)_n$ and then the closed form solution of $(a_n)_n$. I haven't done the calculation yet but I guess that the limit must be $1/x_{1}$ where $x_1$ is the largest root in absolute value of the two roots of the equation $$x^2 = x+b$$ **unless** at the begining (as in your example $(b,a_0) = (2,-1)$), we have $$a_1 = x_2$$ (the second root) and the sequence becomes constant $$x_2 =a_3 =a_4=...=a_n=...$$